# How to unmount and possibly delete old Ubuntu Core snap

Tags: ubuntu-core, snap

When I type:

```
$ mount|grep snap
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/ubuntu-core_352.snap on /snap/ubuntu-core/352 type squashfs (ro,relatime)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/ubuntu-core_423.snap on /snap/ubuntu-core/423 type squashfs (ro,relatime)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/ubuntu-core_122.snap on /snap/ubuntu-core/122 type squashfs (ro,relatime)
```

I see several old snap "mounted" and available while only the latest version is used as *current* in `/snap/ubuntu-core`

It's not a big deal but do I need older ubuntu core ? Isn't this a bug there are not deleted ? Could I simply unmount and delete the files ?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

```
  sudo snap remove core --revision 122
  sudo snap remove core --revision 352
```

So, basically passing the revisions to remove in the command line.

To check the ones you've installed you have to use `snap list [snap-name] --all`

Comment: Considering current package name, up to date command looks like:

`sudo snap remove core --revision 122`

Comment: `snap list --all` to list installed packages with [all revisions](https://superuser.com/a/1318009/500826). Check also [how to remove all disabled](https://askubuntu.com/a/1040131/349837) snap packages.

Answer (score 7):

To completley remove snap core, snap and mounted filesystems:

1. List installed snap cores `snap list --all`
   should give you something like:

   `Name  Version  Rev   Tracking  Publisher   Notes
   core  16-2.41  7713  stable    canonical✓  core,disabled
   core  16-2.42  7917  stable    canonical✓  core`
2. Remove disabled ones first `snap remove core --revision 7713` notice the Rev column in step 1 should match --revision
3. Uninstall snapd (on Ubuntu: `apt-get purge snapd`)
4. Findout if snap is still mounted (for example `df -H`) gives something like
   `/dev/loop0             94M   94M     0 100% /snap/core/7917` and unmount it `umount /snap/core/7917` but it shouldn't
5. If there are still mounted fs-es, you should attempt manual cleanup of **/etc/systemd/system/snap-core-*** something files.

Next time when your server reboots, snaps won't be there, unless you install/remove snapd again from some reason...

Answer (score 4):

So I unmount the old snap:

```
sudo umount /snap/ubuntu-core/122
```

and then done some manual clean up

```
sudo rmdir /snap/ubuntu-core/122
sudo rm /var/lib/snapd/snaps/ubuntu-core_122.snap
```

The same for the other one. The sky did not fall... yet

Comment: In my case, the last command `sudo rm /var/lib/snapd/snaps/ubuntu-core_122.snap` was non necessary.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/tsbertalan/f49f892a58d2a0889358e5b6b64af028 Here's a gist that automates this for multiple mounts. It doesn't actually run its commands; just prints what you would run, which is easy enough to change.

Comment: yout script removes all the snaps. This is not what you want !

Comment: sudo: unmount: command not found .... ?

Comment: Perfect! Finally a way to remove snaps that `snapd` somehow forgot about and does not list in `sudo snap list --all`. Happened to me for the `openscad-nightly` snap for some reason.

Answer (score 3):

This is done, so you can `snap revert` to rollback to an older snap version.