# How to remove Minecraft server from Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: server

Doing snap list for an other problem, I saw minecraft-server-jdstrand.
I do not play that game so I wish to remove this Minecraft

Comment: Follow this thread in AskUbuntu: [How to remove disabled (unused) snap packages with a single line of command?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1036633/how-to-remove-disabled-unused-snap-packages-with-a-single-line-of-command)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
snap remove minecraft-server-jdstrand
```

The system will ask for your password. Provide it.

Yup, it's probably that easy.