# How can I safely remove the ~/Snap folder?

Tags: snap, home-directory, delete, storage

I'd love to delete the Snap folder in my home. It takes 97 GB of space. No package manager should be allowed this amount of space in the /home mount point! 
How can I safely delete Snap and all its content (without breaking dependencies)?

I am really not interested in hiding or moving the Snap folder. I wish to delete it and remove the package that is responsible for it. Really I was happy enough with aptitude.

Comment: Are you sure that the snap folder takes 97 Gb ? It would be verry strange if it is the case.

Comment: or move your home folder to another location https://askubuntu.com/questions/21321/move-home-folder-to-second-drive

Comment: I checked with du -h -d 1 /home/myhome. My goal is to backup my home and shrink my primary partition. But I wasn't aware of hosting such an indecent amount of stuff in my home

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/1040131/289138 -- maybe?

Comment: If you also wish to stop using snaps then go  `sudo apt purge snapd`. This will remove current snaps, prevent further snap installs. (- you'll still need to remove snap folder in home directory yourself

Comment: Perhaps you meant 97 MB and not 97 GB? That said, I have yet to encounter a `snap` I've needed to install. Many of the large developers who provide a `snap` also provide a regular `sudo apt install` version which I use instead.

Comment: Odd, one of my comments was removed (wtf is that about??).. to say again - feel free to remove the ~/snap folder or browse and remove uneeded items. It's only for config type files for snaps and any snap will recreate when run it's local file(s)