# Remove a specific snap package

Tags: package-management, snap

When I run `df -h` I see that I have several `/snap` entries with similar names and sizes. I've edited and rearranged the output, so that similar names all appear together (see below).

I am guessing that I should be able to remove (for example) the earlier instance of Gimp: `/snap/gimp/367`. [This article](https://linuxhint.com/remove-snap-package-ubuntu/) tells me how to reduce a *named* snap package, but I haven't found how to remove just one of two packages with the same name.

Also, which of the `core...` packages do I really need?

Thanks in advance for any help with this.

```
/snap/audacity/857           /dev/loop17     188M  188M     0 100% 
/snap/chromium-ffmpeg/17     /dev/loop11      33M   33M     0 100% 
/snap/core/11167             /dev/loop10     100M  100M     0 100% 
/snap/core/11187             /dev/loop19     100M  100M     0 100% 
/snap/core18/2066            /dev/loop13      56M   56M     0 100% 
/snap/core18/2074            /dev/loop6       56M   56M     0 100% 
/snap/core20/1026            /dev/loop23      62M   62M     0 100% 
/snap/core20/975             /dev/loop14      62M   62M     0 100% 
/snap/gimp/367               /dev/loop22     269M  269M     0 100% 
/snap/gimp/372               /dev/loop21     277M  277M     0 100% 
/snap/gnome-3-28-1804/145    /dev/loop4      163M  163M     0 100% 
/snap/gnome-3-38-2004/39     /dev/loop16     244M  244M     0 100% 
/snap/gtk-common-themes/1514 /dev/loop9       65M   65M     0 100% 
/snap/gtk-common-themes/1515 /dev/loop8       66M   66M     0 100% 
/snap/gtk2-common-themes/13  /dev/loop0      256K  256K     0 100% 
/snap/heroku/4048            /dev/loop2       27M   27M     0 100% 
/snap/opera/128              /dev/loop15     151M  151M     0 100% 
/snap/opera/130              /dev/loop1      151M  151M     0 100% 
/snap/postman/133            /dev/loop18     176M  176M     0 100% 
/snap/skype/173              /dev/loop12     135M  135M     0 100% 
/snap/skype/176              /dev/loop5      136M  136M     0 100% 
/snap/snapd/12057            /dev/loop3       33M   33M     0 100% 
/snap/snapd/12159            /dev/loop20      33M   33M     0 100% 
/snap/telegram-desktop/2637  /dev/loop7      302M  302M     0 100%
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

List your installed snaps with the command

```
snap list --all
```

The output displays, among others, a "Name" (first column) and a "Rev" (revisions, third column) column. Remove a specific revision with a command such as

```
snap remove <Name> --revision <Rev>
```

substituting  and  with what you saw in the output.

Answer (score 5):

Do not remove the core packages. The other snaps depend on them.

If you want to remove gimp altogether, you can remove it with

```
sudo snap remove gimp
```

If you want to remove an old, unused version of gimp or any other package, have a look at [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/q/1036633/124466).

Comment: Question is not how to remove an application (e.g. Gimp) but how to remove earlier archived versions of a snap.