# Huawei E392 is not connecting to the internet

Tags: networking, drivers, usb-modem, huawei

I have tried https://krblogs.com/post/62519969772/airtel-4g-lte-on-linux which solution kept me connecting until error and no internet.

When I tried "$ sudo usb_modeswitch -v 12d1 -p 151a -V 12d1 -P 151b -W -M “55534243123456780000000000000011062000000100000000000000000000″" from https://web.archive.org/web/20151020040737/http://blog.bluedrive.ro/?p=28, I got "Take all parameters from the command line

- usb_modeswitch: handle USB devices with multiple modes
- Version 2.6.1 (C) Josua Dietze 2017
- Based on libusb1/libusbx

! PLEASE REPORT NEW CONFIGURATIONS !

DefaultVendor= 0x12d1
DefaultProduct= 0x151a
TargetVendor= 0x12d1
TargetProduct= 0x151b
MessageContent="“55534243123456780000000000000011062000000100000000000000000000″"

MessageContent “55534243123456780000000000000011062000000100000000000000000000″
is not a hex string. Abort"

I have downloaded "usb-modeswitch-data-20191128.tar.bz2", "usb-modeswitch-2.6.0.tar.bz2" and "libusb-1.0.26" but I do not know how to execute any "make" or use these archives via a simple gui.

I use Huawei E392 with Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS 64-bit (gnome 42.4). I have installed the additional driver suggested by Ubuntu:[image: driver].

I have tried many codes from https://www.google.com/search?q=huawei+e392+ubuntu without any luck.
Please suggest any new ideas!

Comment: have you acces to net over your wlan?

Comment: I access it via mobile hotspot.

Comment: Wow wrong command in mind. `journalctl -f`

Comment: https://justpaste.it/8hpuw - here is the system log.

Comment: This snapd releatet. `snap list` please.  But for this I'm not a great help. I can only imaging, that is maybe some permission problem.

Comment: Please: https://justpaste.it/3pbrj

Comment: I would for test purpose remove snap abeato-usb-modeswitch . make sure you have usb-modeswitch as deb an your system `dpkg -l | grep modeswitch`

Comment: `dpkg -l | grep modeswitch`:  ii  usb-modeswitch                             2.6.1-3ubuntu2                          amd64        mode switching tool for controlling "flip flop" USB devices
ii  usb-modeswitch-data                        20191128-4                              all          mode switching data for usb-modeswitch

Comment: remove the snap https://askubuntu.com/questions/1347910/remove-a-specific-snap-package

Comment: which snap exactly: https://justpaste.it/2yj7z ? I guess the core should be not touched.

Comment: First check please `dpkg  -l | grep modemmanager`if modemmanager is installed over apt; if so you can remove snap`modem-manager`

Comment: `dpkg  -l | grep modemmanager`: ii  modemmanager                               1.18.6-1                                amd64        D-Bus service for managing modems

Comment: Is it installed over apt?

Comment: sorry yes it is. so you can remove the snap one. Make a reboot `journalctl -f` and plug the modem in please.

Comment: after removing the snap one, rebooting, activating `journalctl -f` and plugging the modem: https://justpaste.it/40y5f

Comment: still no internet connection. Anything else to try?

Comment: what does the leftmost icon (https://www.upload.ee/files/14652974/Screenshot_from_2022-11-09_15-32-10.png.html) mean? I have Wi-Fi enabled and mobile broadband connected to the USB but no internet