# Can shrink capacity of snapped core and kde-frameworks packages?

Tags: 22.04, snap

I wrote this [python script](https://askubuntu.com/a/1386544/541417) sometime back and it shows me the following:

```
ALL (ACTIVE & DISABLED) SNAP PACKAGES IN SYSTEM:
Active     391933952    /var/lib/snapd/snaps/anbox_186.snap
Active          4096    /var/lib/snapd/snaps/bare_5.snap
            58281984    /var/lib/snapd/snaps/core18_2632.snap
Active      58314752    /var/lib/snapd/snaps/core18_2654.snap
Active      66301952    /var/lib/snapd/snaps/core20_1738.snap
Active      76398592    /var/lib/snapd/snaps/core22_444.snap
Active     122359808    /var/lib/snapd/snaps/core_14399.snap
            57778176    /var/lib/snapd/snaps/cups_836.snap
Active      57704448    /var/lib/snapd/snaps/cups_872.snap
Active     548626432    /var/lib/snapd/snaps/djpdf_92.snap
Active     172761088    /var/lib/snapd/snaps/gnome-3-28-1804_161.snap
Active     363151360    /var/lib/snapd/snaps/gnome-3-38-2004_119.snap
Active      96141312    /var/lib/snapd/snaps/gtk-common-themes_1535.snap
Active        143360    /var/lib/snapd/snaps/gtk2-common-themes_13.snap
Active     444772352    /var/lib/snapd/snaps/kde-frameworks-5-91-qt-5-15-3-core20_1.snap
Active     457498624    /var/lib/snapd/snaps/kde-frameworks-5-96-qt-5-15-5-core20_7.snap
Active     273375232    /var/lib/snapd/snaps/kde-frameworks-5-core18_32.snap
Active     444768256    /var/lib/snapd/snaps/kde-frameworks-5-qt-5-15-3-core20_8.snap
Active     618799104    /var/lib/snapd/snaps/pycharm-community_310.snap
Active     241647616    /var/lib/snapd/snaps/riseup-vpn_179.snap
            48156672    /var/lib/snapd/snaps/snap-store_599.snap
Active      48160768    /var/lib/snapd/snaps/snap-store_638.snap
              311296    /var/lib/snapd/snaps/snapd-desktop-integration_43.snap
Active        311296    /var/lib/snapd/snaps/snapd-desktop-integration_49.snap
Active      52031488    /var/lib/snapd/snaps/snapd_17883.snap
```

I noticed that these active packages:

```
Active      58314752    /var/lib/snapd/snaps/core18_2654.snap
Active      66301952    /var/lib/snapd/snaps/core20_1738.snap
Active      76398592    /var/lib/snapd/snaps/core22_444.snap
Active     122359808    /var/lib/snapd/snaps/core_14399.snap
```

and

```
Active     444772352    /var/lib/snapd/snaps/kde-frameworks-5-91-qt-5-15-3-core20_1.snap
Active     457498624    /var/lib/snapd/snaps/kde-frameworks-5-96-qt-5-15-5-core20_7.snap
Active     273375232    /var/lib/snapd/snaps/kde-frameworks-5-core18_32.snap
Active     444768256    /var/lib/snapd/snaps/kde-frameworks-5-qt-5-15-3-core20_8.snap
```

are taking up a lot of system storage space. Their size keeps growing and growing. For Ubuntu 22.04 to work, does it really need all the `/var/lib/snapd/snaps/core` and `/var/lib/snapd/snaps/kde-frameworks` packages? Can some of these be deleted?

I am ignorant of why there are so many snapped core files and snapped kde-frameworks files. Are they repeats?

**Update:**

```
$ grep "default-provider:" /snap/*/current/meta/snap.yaml
/snap/djpdf/current/meta/snap.yaml:    default-provider: gtk-common-themes
/snap/djpdf/current/meta/snap.yaml:    default-provider: kde-frameworks-5-96-qt-5-15-5-core20
/snap/djpdf/current/meta/snap.yaml:    default-provider: gtk-common-themes
/snap/snapd-desktop-integration/current/meta/snap.yaml:    default-provider: gnome-3-38-2004
/snap/snapd-desktop-integration/current/meta/snap.yaml:    default-provider: gtk-common-themes
/snap/snapd-desktop-integration/current/meta/snap.yaml:    default-provider: gtk-common-themes
/snap/snapd-desktop-integration/current/meta/snap.yaml:    default-provider: gtk-common-themes
/snap/snap-store/current/meta/snap.yaml:    default-provider: gnome-3-38-2004
/snap/snap-store/current/meta/snap.yaml:    default-provider: gtk-common-themes
/snap/snap-store/current/meta/snap.yaml:    default-provider: gtk-common-themes
/snap/snap-store/current/meta/snap.yaml:    default-provider: gtk-common-themes

$ grep "base:" /snap/*/*/meta/snap.yaml
/snap/cups/872/meta/snap.yaml:base: core20
/snap/cups/current/meta/snap.yaml:base: core20
/snap/djpdf/92/meta/snap.yaml:base: core20
/snap/djpdf/current/meta/snap.yaml:base: core20
/snap/gnome-3-28-1804/161/meta/snap.yaml:base: core18
/snap/gnome-3-28-1804/current/meta/snap.yaml:base: core18
/snap/gnome-3-38-2004/119/meta/snap.yaml:base: core20
/snap/gnome-3-38-2004/current/meta/snap.yaml:base: core20
/snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/meta/snap.yaml:base: bare
/snap/gtk-common-themes/current/meta/snap.yaml:base: bare
/snap/kde-frameworks-5-91-qt-5-15-3-core20/1/meta/snap.yaml:base: core20
/snap/kde-frameworks-5-91-qt-5-15-3-core20/current/meta/snap.yaml:base: core20
/snap/kde-frameworks-5-96-qt-5-15-5-core20/7/meta/snap.yaml:base: core20
/snap/kde-frameworks-5-96-qt-5-15-5-core20/current/meta/snap.yaml:base: core20
/snap/kde-frameworks-5-core18/32/meta/snap.yaml:base: core18
/snap/kde-frameworks-5-core18/current/meta/snap.yaml:base: core18
/snap/kde-frameworks-5-qt-5-15-3-core20/8/meta/snap.yaml:base: core20
/snap/kde-frameworks-5-qt-5-15-3-core20/current/meta/snap.yaml:base: core20
/snap/pycharm-community/310/meta/snap.yaml:base: core18
/snap/pycharm-community/312/meta/snap.yaml:base: core18
/snap/pycharm-community/current/meta/snap.yaml:base: core18
/snap/snapd-desktop-integration/49/meta/snap.yaml:base: core20
/snap/snapd-desktop-integration/current/meta/snap.yaml:base: core20
/snap/snap-store/638/meta/snap.yaml:base: core20
/snap/snap-store/current/meta/snap.yaml:base: core20
```

Comment: Like deb-packages, snaps have dependencies (other snaps). You can try the commands in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1236201/590937) to see the dependencies of your snaps.

Comment: @mook765 I have added what I found using your comment and answer. It seems that `core18` and `core20` is in use. However, `core22_444` and `core_14399` do not seem to be in use and yet it appears as `Active`.Why is this so? Can `core22_444` and `core_14399` be removed then?

Comment: Looks like you don't need them. You might have a snap installed and then later removed which needed them, so now they are left over. You'll have to run `sudo systemctl stop snap-core-14399.mount` and `sudo systemctl stop snap-core22-444.mount` and then `snap remove --purge core` and `snap remove --purge core22` if you want to remove them.