# How do I uninstall snaps no longer depended on?

Tags: snap

I am looking for a way to remove snap packages that are no longer depended upon, similar to `apt autopurge`/`apt autoremove` for `.deb`/dpkg packages.

###### What does apt autoremove do?

It removes packages that were installed as dependencies, recommendations, or suggestions of other packages, but are no longer marked as such after an update, or because the original package has since been uninstalled.

###### But snap packages are dependencyless

Contrary to this common misconception, anyone who installs a common snap (eg. `snap install firefox`), will see that  several other snaps are installed as its dependency, such as `gtk-common-themes`, `gnome-<version>`, `core<version>`, and others that are in turn dependencies of these.

So, this question has been incorrectly marked as a duplicate.

###### Just remove the snap

The question is not how to remove a snap, but how to remove all automatically installed ones that are no longer needed. Finding out which snaps are no longer depended on is non-trivial when there are hundreds of them installed.

Comment: No, `apt autopurge` removes packages that are no longer needed. I'm looking for the snap equivalent to that... removing snaps that were installed as dependencies but aren't needed anymore, eg. the depending snap was uninstalled, updated, etc.

Comment: Snap packages do not have *dependencies* like *deb* packages..  All *dependencies* are included within the *snap* package itself and thus get removed when the main *squashfs* file is removed. The definition of *snap* says "*Snaps are app packages for desktop, cloud and IoT that are easy to install, secure, cross-platform and dependency-free.*"

Comment: @guiverc This is clearly incorrect, which you can see yourself if you install a snap, for example `snap install firefox` and it will also install `gtk-common-themes`, `gnome-3-38-2004` or similar, `core20` or `core18`, and `bare`. So the question stands

Comment: Those are not *dependencies* which was a design purpose of *snap* packages.   Yes it's easy to think of them that way (esp. if thinking in *deb* package terms) but they're not called *dependencies*.  Snap packagers can implement everything internally; or build using shared/common packages to save disk space/resources... This can be seen in the file `/snap/firefox/current/snap/snapcraft.yaml` for firefox; but they're not *dependencies*  (but *plugs*).  The base is different; *snap* packages built for Ubuntu Core 16 will require `core16`.. but that's still an important *plug* called *base*.

Comment: Regardless of terminology, after an update, people end up with several versions of `core` for example that no other snap needs any more, because it moved to `core18`, then `core20`, etc etc. So `core16` will still be installed but unnecessarily. So the question is, how to remove these stale packages that are left behind?

Comment: Probably [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1141683/349837) was you were looking for, `snap list --all | awk '$6~"disabled"{print $1" --revision "$3}' | xargs -rn3 sudo snap remove`

Comment: @PabloBianchi I think that removes _disabled_ snaps and I'm looking to remove "unused" or "orphaned" ones. Unless that's the same thing, but I don't think so.. it looks like I have _enabled_ but unused snaps for example `gnome-3-38-2004`

Comment: In other words, snapd doesn't track plugs/dependencies/prerequisites and users have to manually clean up the mess left behind by uninstalled snaps?