# How can I reject automatic Install-Recommends for snap?

Tags: software-installation, snap

I am using `APT::Install-Recommends "false"` in `/etc/apt/apt.conf` to restrict my machine to software I deliberately installed. I still remain free to later accept such recommendation.

This mechanism does not seem to apply to *snaps*. During unattended updates `openprinting/cups` and `brlin/hunspell-dictionaries-1-7-2004` were installed, neither of which is was necessary for any other installed snap, and neither of which was authorized.

I would like to prevent this from happening again. If necessary, even limiting unattended installation to Canonical-supported software, throwing an error when requested updates are impossible under such policy. What are my options?

Comment: Related: [Snap equivalent of the apt-get autopurge command?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1446531/snap-equivalent-of-the-apt-get-autopurge-command)

Comment: There is no way to configure this.

Comment: Never say never :D

Answer (score 0):

### Snap retention|refresh|pinning|autoremove

A [often](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1408591/how-do-i-uninstall-snaps-no-longer-depended-on) [discussed](https://superuser.com/questions/1310825/how-to-remove-old-version-of-installed-snaps) [question](https://snapcraft.io/blog/how-to-keep-your-linux-disk-usage-nice-and-tidy-and-save-space) ... with a bunch of half-answers.

Since snap has no package systems that just upgrades in place ,
snap pulls dependencys with the packages and also keeps a copy of the last n versions of snaps

( and you are right if you think that snap uses your local storage
like a mirrored registry with the last n versions )

#### Current State of Snap Auto-Cleaning:

[In fact there is a Feature proposal since 2022 ( ~3 Years )](https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/automatic-snapshots-snap-remove-purge-proposal/11294/14) ,
so maybe spread some votes there ..

### Snap CleanUp / AutoPurge Ways:

The closes to "auto-pruning" you can get:

- [Engage the auto-clean script to get rid of old versions](https://gitlab.com/-/snippets/1927120) ( [found here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1200763/748482) )
- disable autos-snapshots , their manual says it all:

  `sudo snap set system snapshots.automatic.retention=no`
  will disable it

  > Automatic snapshot retention time is configured with the
  > snapshots.automatic.retention system option.
  > The default value is 31 days, and the value needs to be greater than 24 hours

  ...

  > **Disabling automatic snapshots will not affect preexisting, automatically generated snapshots, but only those generated by subsequent snap removals.**
- clean up the snapshots, [there is a very good example script](https://gist.github.com/alanorth/fdaa3f3be16b58822a4a876afbd62604)

**There is no "exact-same" apt(-get) way of saving more space with snap** ,
but amongst the top-tips there are:

- Lower the "old versions" snapd keeps:
  `sudo snap set system refresh.retain=2`

  > The refresh.retain value can be a number between 2 and 20.
  > The default is refresh.retain=3 on Ubuntu Core systems
  > and refresh.retain=2 on classic Ubuntu systems,
  > such as those running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (Bionic Beaver)
  > and Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (Xenial Xerus).
- clear the cache:
  `sudo find /var/lib/snapd/cache/ -exec rm -v {} \;  # Remove cache`

### The "Dangerous" non-moving part: locking against updates with `refresh --hold`

###### Preamble: You might run into outdated software and resulting security issues , so please be careful and update regularly by reinstalling or unholding the lock.

Your inital question also included:

> even limiting unattended installation to Canonical-supported software
> well

There was currently no way found  to do this,
except "pinning"( snap term "refresh hold")

#### How-To: snapd pinning

- since 2.58+, there is refresh lock holding ( apt pinning equivalent )
- it might be issued for one or all packages , with and without timelimit
- `snap refresh --hold` "should" lock all updates
- a specific example is `sudo snap refresh --hold=24h firefox`

#### How-To: update snapd "pinned" software

- Variant A to update (firefox example), either  `sudo snap remove --purge firefox`,`sudo snap install` ,`sudo snap refresh --hold` ,
- Variant B to update `sudo snap refresh --unhold firefox`,`sudo snap refresh firefox`,`sudo snap refresh --hold`

Comment: This answer was likely supposed to go under the [related question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1446531/snap-equivalent-of-the-apt-get-autopurge-command) about what to to after the fact

Comment: don't know if doubleposting is OK (?) .. i've added the `refresh hold` method for you , that is currently the closest you might get to your desired behaviour. regards